# Populate table vertically with multiple columns with DOMPDF

Tags: php, dompdf

I want to fill a table as follows in DOMPDF. That it has 4 columns and that it goes filling by column. In the first row of the first column, you start by placing the name under goals and assists, and then your goals and assists by season are placed in each row. If there is no space left in that column, it goes to the next one. And it continues to fill, when that player is finished filling, it goes to the next player, just below where it left off. The name of soccer player 2 and assisted goals are placed, and the data of that player is reviewed. When the 4 columns are full, you go to the next sheet. So until the end of the process.

Here I leave an example, just in case I don't explain myself well (The data is not real, I only put it as an example).

```
Page 1
Footballer's Name       15      10                6       6              
  Goals Assist          13      8                 18      11                
   25     22            21      22                15      17
   16     18            16      15            Footballer's Name 3 
   20     13          Footballer's Name 2        Goals  Assist
   30     12           Goals   Assist             20      15
   15     18           16        14               21      16
   30     25           42        20                .
   44     16           30        15                .
   8      13           25        25                .
```